# How to wire 2.5mm female port?

Tags: arduino, audio, wire

I purchased a 2.5mm TRS socket to receive LANC signals. I am try to wire it to an Arduino Mega. Am brand new to this.

The connections for LANC are this:

T = LANC protocol
R = 5V DC
S = Ground.

The connector has 3 prongs on it but they don't seem to be labelled and I can't find anything that distinguishes the tip, ring and sleeve. So can anyone help with that?

Bonus points if anyone can tell me where they go on the Arduino.

Thanks a lot

[image: My 2.5mm jack]

Comment: Do you have a male 2.5mm plug available? You can plug it in and use continuity check to see where the conductors connect.

Comment: I do yes. I'm unfamiliar with "continuity" though

Comment: Continuity check on a multimeter is just a special mode of the resistance measurement function. It is usually either on the lowest range or is its own setting, signified with a sound icon (http://www.cdn.sciencebuddies.org/Files/4815/6/continuity-check-symbols.jpg). It will make a beep when the resistance is very low. This lets you check what is connected to what without having to look at the meter.

Comment: My multimeter does have that option. I'm in a similar boat with my male connector though, I don't know which plug is which.

I have a remote plugged in to the female, but no idea where to place the multimeter prongs now.

Comment: Ah, but on that one the mating part is exposed, so you can touch the tip, ring, and sleeve and check against its pins. Then once you know how its pins are wired you can plug it into the female part and do the check again to find how it is wired.

Comment: look at the other side of the socket and it shoulf be obvious which is which.

Comment: I know what TRS means (tip, ring and sleeve). I have the multimeter in resistance mode and *think* I've figured it out for the male plug at least. I'll need a bit of time with my big fingers to get this down.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Austin, was able to determine.

[image]